# Как правильно написать запрос к БД PDO

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных, pdo

Нужно написать стандартный запрос к БД используя `PDO php` ничего сложного. Вот запрос, который я использую:

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
$result = $db->query("SELECT login, id FROM shops WHERE login LIKE '%$text%'");
return $result->fetchAll();
```

Запрос возвращает массив данных, которые возвращают одну и ту же запись 2 раза т.е так:

```
Array ( [login] => логин [0] => логин [id] => 10 [1] => 10 )
```

Ну соответственно задается вопрос если работать с большим объемом данных не скажется ли это на скорости выполнения запроса? И как написать правильный запрос к БД чтобы он возвращал массив без раздвоения данных?

Comment: как ни странно, но данная ситуация весьма подробно расписана в документации. в том числе и ситуация с передачей параметров в запрос, которая в вашем случае сделана не корректно и не безопасно.

Comment: @teran Не безопасно? Насколько я знаю PDO не позволяет делать sql инъекцию или что вы имели ввиду под словом не безопасно???

Comment: @AziretKadykeev, это если правильно писать запросы. А у вас явно неправильно написан запрос (с точки зрения безопасности)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно будет использовать биндинг параметров при выполнении запроса и извлечение только именованных (или наоборот) столбцов результирующего набора.

```
$sql = 'SELECT login, id FROM shops WHERE login LIKE :txt';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute( [':txt' => "%{$text}%"] );
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```